# How to handle errors for ParameterizedQuery?

Tags: pg-promise

The docs for [ParameterizedQuery](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html) state:

> The type can be used in place of the query parameter, with any query method directly. And **it never throws any error**, leaving it for query methods to reject with ParameterizedQueryError.

What exactly does this mean?

- does it mean that the constructor of [ParameterizedQuery](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html) never throws an error or does it never throw when we execute the query?
- how are we supposed to handle the errors?
  i.e. when are we supposed to throw [ParameterizedQueryError](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/errors.ParameterizedQueryError.html)?

E.g. currently my function looks like this:

```
async foo() {
    const pq = new ParameterizedQuery({
      text: 'Select ..',
      values: [repoRequest.limit],
      rowMode: 'array'
    });

    return transaction.manyOrNone(pq);
}
```

and it seems to work fine (same as with a text-query parameter) - it will also throw an error at execution time, when the query is erronous.

Comment: I have removed that sentence from the API documentation, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it mean that the constructor of ParameterizedQuery never throws an error or does it never throw when we execute the query?

Yes. Errors from Parameterized Queries manifest themselves in the same way as with all queries in the library - through promise rejection.

**UPDATE**

I have removed that sentence from the API documentation, to avoid confusion.